# Using Java to print upside down right triangle with Astericks for a lab

Tags: java

I'm currently taking a programming course at my university and I'm stuck on this lab exercise where we have to print this shape:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

The code I have prints the shape but it's right side up and I can't figure out how to get it in the upside down pattern. here's the code I have typed up

```
final int max_rows = 10; //The Shape is 10 rows long

for (int row = 1; row <= max_rows; row++)
{
    for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
        System.out.print ("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Change the first loop to count the other way: `for (int row = max_rows; row >= 1; row--)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
final int max_rows = 10; //The Shape is 10 rows long

    for (int row = max_rows; row > 0; row--)
    {
       for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
          System.out.print ("*");

          System.out.println();
       }
    }
```

I reversed the first for loop, starting with the `max_rows` and looping until `max_rows` is 0.

Comment: It worked thanks alot. I am very new to coding and so far I have enjoyed it and I can kinda see myself doing it in the future as a career but I'm trying not to let the fact that rn I'm a complete rookie discourage me.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Just keep practicing and asking questions! Everyone has to start somewhere! :)